# Django server is not running after added a new path function

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I have created an app name 'calc' in Django and in the app, I have edited two files codes.
**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path


from . import views

urlpattern = [
    path('', views.home, name='home')
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
# Create your views here.

def home(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello Django!")
```

and finally, I have changed my directory folder's file 
**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('calc.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

now I am running the command on terminal: **python manage.py runserver** 
and it's giving me these below errors and not connecting to the server.
**terminal errors:**

```
* Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Shuvra\Envs\docu\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 590, in url_patterns
    iter(patterns)
TypeError: 'module' object is not iterable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\shuvra\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "c:\users\shuvra\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Shuvra\Envs\docu\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Shuvra\Envs\docu\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\Shuvra\Envs\docu\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 392, in check
    all_issues = self._run_checks(
  File "C:\Users\Shuvra\Envs\docu\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 382, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Shuvra\Envs\docu\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Users\Shuvra\Envs\docu\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\Shuvra\Envs\docu\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\Shuvra\Envs\docu\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 408, in check
    messages.extend(check_resolver(pattern))
  File "C:\Users\Shuvra\Envs\docu\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\Shuvra\Envs\docu\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 407, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\Shuvra\Envs\docu\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Shuvra\Envs\docu\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 597, in url_patterns
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf '<module 'calc.urls' from 'C:\\Users\\Shuvra\\Documents\\Dev\\hellodjango\\calc\\urls.py'>' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.
```

Comment: did you save your app inside setting INSTALLED APP?

Comment: INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

Comment: I don't get it.

Comment: so you have created a app call calc soo you gotta register it inside INSTALL_APP. just add calc inside it.

Comment: update: INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'calc',
]
but same errors. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see simple typo mistake..
in your urls.py there should be `urlpatterns=[]` instead you have `urlpattern=[]`

Answer (score -1):

You have created two paths in both urls.py for the / page. As I know this is not the correct way. you could do this in you url

```
path('', include('calc.urls')),

path('home/', views.home, name='home')
```

and than load it will localhost:8000/home/ and it will work